# What is the subject when it's omitted after the comparison?

Tags: ellipsis, comparison, comparative-constructions, formality

> As market forces penetrate firms and bid up the value of attributes of labor that are more measurable than ***is*** the knowledge born of experience, it can be expected that trends in wages will not favor those whose main value lies in such experiential knowledge.

What is the subject after "than" for "is the knowledge born of experience"? How to complete this sentence? Here's my own try:

"As market forces penetrate firms and bid up the value of attributes of labor that are more measurable than (the value of) the knowledge born of experience is, it can be...."

Am I right when completing it in this way? Thanks!

Comment: The subject of *is* is *the knowledge born of experience*. This part of the sentence can also be written *...than the knowledge born of experience is (measurable)*. There is no ellipsis of *the value of*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of ***subject/verb inversion***, not a case of *ellipsis* as you said. We use this kind of inversion while *comparing subjects* of the verb and not normally *objects*. We call it *inversion in comparatives* as in

> Paul is more interested in Maths than is Mary.
>
> You play golf better than do I.

So in this sentence, there is *no ellipsis* of the subject. The subject is actually there after *is* which is *the knowledge born of experience*. Actually a simpler way to write what is there in your example is

> ... more measurable than the knowledge born of experience *is*

Comment: Azad@,, Can we omit "is" and rewrite the sentence "Paul is more interested in Maths than Mary" ?

Comment: This type of inversion is optional. Yes, you can also say _than Mary is_. _than Mary_ is very common, though it's not encouraged in formal written language.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought the sentence has no "is" now I know it is just omitted in spoken language.

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Comment: @GamalThomas Note that "Paul is more interested in Maths than Mary" can be ambiguous, as it can compare "Maths" with "Mary", as well as it can compare "Paul" with "Mary". The ambiguity is usually not a problem, though, as common sense usually can tell us which meaning was intended. ;-)

Comment: @Damkerng, thank you, its a very useful notice for me.